# Same Code on different hosts, one works one doesn't

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm developing a Webpage and want to use WebSockets for live events.

As backend I'm using redis with a nodejs subscriber that calls socket.io to send the events to the clients.

But my problem starts within the first row of my script.

```
var express = require('express')();
// ...
```

On my Server (Ubuntu 16.04, nodejs v6.6.0, express v4.14.0) it works perfect,
but in my development vm (Ubuntu 16.04, nodejs v6.6.0, express v4.14.0) it says (**EDIT** new error message):

```
server.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var express = require('express')();
                                                                                              ^
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at ...
```

Has anyone an idea why this happens?

Also the expressjs.com homepage says:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Here is a workflow overview:
[image: event workflow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I wrote in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603281/same-code-on-different-hosts-one-works-one-doesnt#comment66526959_39603362) on Sep 21 '16 the solution to this problem was to:

`rm -rf node_modules`
and
`npm install`

Answer (score 1):

You do either this:

```
var app = require('express')();
```

or this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

You don't do this:

```
var express = require('express')();
var app = express();
```

The only difference between the first two options is whether you save the `express` module or not for future reference.

The third one is just wrong and would generate the error you report because at that point `express` in the third one is an app object, not a function.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, that was a bad mistake by me. But unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. I updated my question, now i'm getting `require(...) is not a function`

Comment: @PKeidel - That now sounds like it is not properly finding and loading the `express` module.  Are you sure you have it installed properly on that server?

Comment: Is `express` in your `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @jfriend00 I installed nodejs like described at https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: @qxz yes, `express` exists in the `node_modules` folder

Comment: @PKeidel - Express is not built into nodejs.  So, a typical isntallation of nodejs does not include Express..  Instead, Express is a separate module that must be installed on it's own after you isntall nodejs if you want to use it.

Comment: @PKeidel - You can test things by doing this:  `var express = require('express');   console.log(express)` and see if you get the express interface object you expect.  It should be a function with properties.

Comment: @qxz @jfriend00 thanks for your help, I finally got it working by deleting the whole `node_modules` folder and installed the modules again via `npm install ...`.